# accessing /gcm-demo/sendAll. Reason: HTTP Status Code: 401

Tags: java, android

i am getting the following Error when i try to send a Message:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /gcm-demo/sendAll. Reason:

HTTP Status Code: 401
Caused by:

com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 401
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:177)
at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
at com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.doPost(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:82)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Powered by Jetty://
```

I am using the Android Example Project as told here: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html

Can somebody help me out? Where is this error coming from?

I am using Jetty on a Linux machine and compiling it to a .war on a Windows Machine using Apache Ant...

Answer (score 2):

you can put the following code into the doPost() method before send messages:

```
import com.google.android.gcm.server.*;

Sender sender = new Sender(myApiKey);
Message message = new Message.Builder().build();
MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, devices, 5);
```

Comment: Can you please share the difference of Result and MulticastResult? Sample coding on follows,              Result res = sender.send(message, regId, 5);
            String id = res.getMessageId();
            String cregId = res.getCanonicalRegistrationId();
            String errorCode = res.getErrorCodeName();

Answer (score 0):

The sender is probably not authorized with google correctly.

`Sender sender = new Sender(MY_KEY);`

Is MY_KEY the same key that you registered with google ? Replace the API key as shown on the [documentation page](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html)

Comment: documentation link is expired, if possible please update it to latest link.

Answer (score 0):

In a text editor, edit the samples/gcm-demo-server/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/api.key and replace the existing text with the API key obtained above.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/demo.html